# Wordpress admin edit-post screen: filter both custom posts and regular posts by category

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added a filter on `pre_get_posts` to merge a custom post type with the regular posts in the edit-post screen. 
All posts are listed but when I try to filter these posts by category, I got an

> "invalid post type" error.

Indeed, the `post_type` parameter in the query string is set to "`(...)&post_type=Array(...)"`

Is this possible using some other hook or filter?

```
// show custom posts in the admin posts list
function Myplugin_posts_add_custom( $query ) {

  $screen = get_current_screen();

  if ( is_admin() && $screen->base == 'edit' && $screen->id == 'edit-post' && $screen->post_type == 'post' ) :

    $post_types = array('post', 'my_custom_post'); 
    $query->set( 'post_type', $post_types );

    return $query;
  endif;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'Myplugin_posts_add_custom' );
```

Thanks for you help